# Meu Modal fica em modo fade

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="width:100%; background-color:rgba(163,196,209, 0.5);">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="max-width:1584px">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header text-center">
                            <h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title w-100" style="text-align:center"><div id="title_modal"></div></h4>
                            <button id="btn-close" type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="close" 
                                onclick="xajax_vista_refresh();xajax_vista_busca_dados(xajax.getFormValues(\'container\'));"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" style="padding-bottom: 0rem;">
                            <div id="modal_content"></div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div id="modal_footer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Pessoal, estou criando o modal acima, onde trago alguns dados do banco de dados e permito deletar/editar e incluir. Até aí ok, funciona corretamente, mas também permito incluir o anexo, onde a inclusão do BLOB está funcionando corretamente. O problema é exatamente depois que o anexo (blob) é incluído, pois apresento um alerta de sucesso, mas o modal está desaparecendo e mantendo o efeito fade, sem permitir que a página retorne (a não ser que seja recarregada, e após recarregar o anexo apareça incluso, isso ou seja, o problema não está na inclusão do blob).

Segue jquery usado em outros botões que funcionam quando o anexo não é adicionado.

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('#table').load(location.href + ' #table');
```

Onde o modal é retirado e a tabela atualizada para apresentação ao cliente. No entanto, como mencionado anteriormente, o modal desaparece e o efeito fade permanece, sendo necessário recarregar a página. Vale ressaltar, essa funcionalidade ocorre mesmo sem a implementação do jquery citado, dando a impressão de que após o alerta (ao inserir o blob) ele "trava" o php, não permitindo o uso do jquery.

Qualquer sugestão aceita por favor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar a questão através do [**AJAX**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

No botão **Salvar** do modal eu estava adicionando a função:

`onclick="salvarAlteracao(\''.$requisicao.'\', \''.$pedido.'\', \''.$data_fin.'\'); xajax_vista_busca_dados(xajax.getFormValues(\'container\'));`.

Porém ao juntar as duas funções estava ocorrendo o erro (provavelmente o PHP estava se perdendo na ordem dos fatores), onde estava executando primeiramente a consulta (recarregando o modal) e posteriormente a execução do SQL. Com isso não tinha mais o modal para que pudesse ser fechado onde a função para fechar o modal já teria sido executada .

`$('#myModal').modal('hide'); $('#table').load(location.href + ' #table');`

Para correção eu adicionei o **AJAX** no inicio da função (`salvarAlteracao(\''.$requisicao.'\', \''.$pedido.'\', \''.$data_fin.'\');`) que será chamada ao selecionar o botão **Salvar**.

`xajax_vista_busca_dados(xajax.getFormValues(\'container\'))`

Assim está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).